# NoClassDefFoundError Error in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, runtime-error, noclassdeffounderror

So after going through many posts on SO and revising some java basics, I still get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2694)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
```

I know the difference between `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and `ClassNotFoundException` in Java, and have looked through what usually causes it. In a nutshell, it is because some class is unavailable to the program during Run Time but is available during Compile time. Hence I get no compile time errors.

I have added two classpaths, one to `commons-logging-1.1.3.jar` and the other to the `hadoop-core.*jar`.
I am pretty confident that the classpaths are correct.

Here are the imports in my Program

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.Writer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.*;
```

Comment: This class is in hadoop-core jar, can you write exactly how you run your job (including the classpath)?

Comment: @CharlesMenguy I use ubuntu 12.04, this is the command line for compiling it 
javac -cp "/home/hduser/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar:/home/hduser/Documents/commons-logging-1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar" TSVtoSeq.java
To Run, 
java TSVtoSeq TrainingT1.tsv testOutput
2 arguments are passed to main, Input File and Output file

Comment: Are you not setting your classpath with `java -cp $JARS` when you run your program?

Comment: @CharlesMenguy So, I added the classpaths while running the program(Is it necessary though?), I still get the same exception thrown. However, the class now being pointed to is  "org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration" instead of "org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable"

Comment: @shashlearner thats becoz there are lots of jars hadoop is dependent on (can be found in HADOOP_HOME/lib) and at runtime several of those get referred to. Either keep doing manual trial-n-error untill u get it running or add all of those jars in the classpath while you run it. A standard way is to create a jar of your code and run using bin/hadoop script as described in my answer below.

Comment: You should look at @TejasP 's solution which is probably the correct one for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a jar out of the java code like given [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred_tutorial.html#Usage):

```
$ mkdir my_classes 
$ javac -classpath $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-$HADOOP_VERSION-core.jar -d my_classes <name of the main class> 
$ jar -cvf <name of the jar> -C my_classes .
```

Run the jar this way:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar <name of the jar> <name of the main class> <arguments to the program>
```

See the [documentation page](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#jar) of hadoop for the description of jar command.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have done exactly what they've asked in their documentation [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/mapred_tutorial.html#Usage)
On running, I get a new error, which is:
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount**

Comment: @shashlearner the one that i gave was for wordcount example. dont blindly use that command. u need to replace things with your class names.

Comment: @shashlearner ok. could you provide these details: the commands you used, your source code, the error u got etc.

Comment: Thanks! 
Hadoop Root : /home/hduser/hadoop
My source code is here: /home/hduser/hadoop/TST_CLASS/hello/WordCount.java
Source Code is the exact core in the Documentation [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/mapred_tutorial.html#Usage)
/home/hduser/hadoop/TST_CLASS/hello/MANIFEST.MF
MANIFEST.MF contains a single line : Main-Class: org.myorg.WordCount
/home/hduser/hadoop/TST_CLASS/hello/commons-logging-1.1.3-tests.jar

I first compile the WordCount.java using: sudo javac -classpath /home/hduser/hadoop/hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar  WordCount.java

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30964/discussion-between-shashlearner-and-tejasp)